# Can't compile Aviary on iOS since SDK 4.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, aviary

I can't run my app only on the iOS Simulator since I updated to Aviary SDK 4.4.
I can run the app on my iPhone and iPad.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: 30 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

The framework and the bundle are visible in "Link binaries with Libraries" and "Bundle ressources".

The Framework search path is OK in build settings.

It looks like the Aviary framework was managed twice ?

I leave/restart Xcode, clean the app in iOS simulator, clean target and destroy DerivedData without success.

Very strange I have no problems in the real devices.

Comment: Aviary has been bought by Adobe and moved into [Adobe's SDK](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/downloads.html#). Having said that, I have not been able to install and compile the Adobe SDK equivalent of Aviary successfully by following [their instructions](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageediting/index.html).

Comment: OK. This morning I received the email update from Aviary. That's why I installed the last version from Aviary website, not from Creative SDK website. I will test too.

Comment: Just got an email back from Adobe Support, they said they just fixed an issue with the SDK, and asked me to redownload. Wanted to let you know in case you downloaded it yesterday, give it a redownload today.

Comment: I am also having an issue in moving our app using the AviarySDK to the Adobe Creative SDK. It seems that it is trying to find the AviarySDKResource.

Comment: It is still broken for me today. Did you get this working with a new version? Do you have a direct link?

Comment: how can i get this sdk @reallyseth

Comment: @MayankPatel [From here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/downloads.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this problem resolved. Here is how:

### Solution

Do not use `#import <AviarySDK/AviarySDK.h>`, instead of that, import the classes that you're using directly. Like: `#import <AviarySDK/AVYPhotoEditorController.h>` etc.

### Reason

The reason I believe lies in the newly introduced `AVYPhotoEditorCompatibility.h`, which is by default included in `<AviarySDK/AviarySDK.h>`.

I think here is the problematic code that is using `typedef` with `const`

```
typedef AVYPhotoEditorPremiumAddOn AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOn AVY_PREMIUM_ADDON_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
AVY_PREMIUM_ADDON_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOn const AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOnNone = AVYPhotoEditorPremiumAddOnNone;
AVY_PREMIUM_ADDON_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOn const AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOnHiRes = AVYPhotoEditorPremiumAddOnHiRes;
AVY_PREMIUM_ADDON_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOn const AFPhotoEditorPremiumAddOnWhiteLabel = AVYPhotoEditorPremiumAddOnWhiteLabel;
```

Comment: Thanks! This fix worked well for me. Also worth noting the Cocoapod for Aviary 4.4.0 has been updated.

Comment: I have almost 10 emails in a conversation with Adobe support and they couldn't figure this one out.  Thanks Tonny!